# How to add data attribute without value in react create element?

Tags: html, reactjs, custom-data-attribute

I am adding `div` to the DOM as below,

`React.createElement("div", { className: "test"});`

The rendered html should be as below

```
<div class="test" data-test>
</div>
```

Where can I add `data-test` in the `createElement`?

Answer (score 4):

If you refer to the doc on [createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) API, you can insert the value to your data-test prop like this:

```
React.createElement('div', {className: 'test', 'data-test': 'some value'});
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code: `data-test` must be quoted.

Comment: @elektronik Good catch! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because attribute without any value means that this attribute has value `true` in JSX. Just don't pass `data-test` and `this.props['data-test']` will be undefined in your component. Or if you need to have this attribute with empty value then just add it to your default values in component definition.

```
defaultProps: {
    'data-test': ''
}
```

Comment: Also, read more here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue and allowed my to add an attribute without value to my html tag.